# opencv reverse perspective transformation?

Tags: opencv, perspective

I start with the following image:

Using opencv I rotate 45° about the Y axis to get the following:

[image]

[image]

If I tried a little harder I could get it not to be cropped in the foreground.

Now my question: does opencv have the tools to do the reverse transformation? Could I take the second image and produce the first? (Not concerned about blurred pixels.)  Please suggest a method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You already made a homography matrix to produce this picture, right?

Just **invert it** (`H.inv()`) or [pass the `WARP_INVERSE_MAP` flag](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87).

No need for all that other stuff.

Comment: Now wait a minute.  As I understand it, perspective transformation involves a division and cannot be expressed by matrix multiplication alone.  Right?  So how could matrix inversion be adequate?

Comment: that's what the third dimension is for. it's the additional dimension in the projective space. the division happens *afterwards*, moving from projective space to "flat" space. -- your question sounds as if you'll reject this stuff entirely if I don't give you a satisfactory answer, so you should grab a math book instead of putting me on the spot here. believe it or not. you should not be surprised that a homography, which is a simple matrix, can do perspective transformations, because you already used a homography matrix to create your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. After 45° rotation, there are some regions below and above are missing(not seen). You only can not get those parts back.

By using [warpPerspective()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) and [getPerspectiveTransform()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae) together, you can easily get back to the first image. Only thing you need to consider is that you should fid the end points of rotated image. Such as: `left_up` , `right_up` , `left_down` , `right_down` respectively. Since you didn't specify the language, I used C++ to implement the functions. Here is the output and code:

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{

    cv::Mat begin = cv::imread("/ur/img/dir/input.jpg");
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::Point2f Poly2[4] = {
                  cv::Point2f(31,9),
                  cv::Point2f(342,51),
                  cv::Point2f(28,571),
                  cv::Point2f(345,525),   //points I got from looking in paint.


    };

    cv::Point2f Points[4] = {
                  cv::Point2f(0,0),
                  cv::Point2f(432,0),
                  cv::Point2f(0,576),       //The picture I want to transform to.
                  cv::Point2f(432,576),

    };



    cv::Mat Matrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform( Poly2,Points);

    cv::warpPerspective(begin, output, Matrix, cv::Size(432, 576));

    cv::imshow("Input", begin);
    cv::imshow("Output", output);


    cv::imwrite("/home/yns/Downloads/tt2.jpg",output);
    cv::waitKey(0);


    return 0;
}
```